# Export DataGridView to Excel (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel)

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, datagridview

I'm trying to export datagridview content to Excel but I encountered the following problem.

The code that I used is below (taken from code.msdn.microsoft.com)

```
private void ExportToExcel()
    {
        // Creating a Excel object.
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet worksheet = null;

        try
        {

            worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;

            worksheet.Name = "ExportedFromDatGrid";

            int cellRowIndex = 1;
            int cellColumnIndex = 1;

            //Loop through each row and read value from each column.
            for (int i = 0; i < DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < DataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    // Excel index starts from 1,1. As first Row would have the Column headers, adding a condition check.
                    if (cellRowIndex == 1)
                    {
                        worksheet.Cells[cellRowIndex, cellColumnIndex] = DataGridView1.Columns[j].HeaderText;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        worksheet.Cells[cellRowIndex, cellColumnIndex] = DataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                    }
                    cellColumnIndex++;
                }
                cellColumnIndex = 1;
                cellRowIndex++;
            }

            //Getting the location and file name of the excel to save from user.
            SaveFileDialog saveDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
            saveDialog.Filter = "Excel files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            saveDialog.FilterIndex = 2;

            if (saveDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                workbook.SaveAs(saveDialog.FileName);
                MessageBox.Show("Export Successful");
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            excel.Quit();
            workbook = null;
            excel = null;
        }
    }
```

Previously, I added the reference Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel to my project from Reference manager / COM section (Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object library). Despite that I received the next error messages:

-> The type name _Application does not exist in the type 'Office.Interop.Excel'

-> The type name _Workbook does not exist in the type 'Office.Interop.Excel'

-> The type name _Worksheet does not exist in the type 'Office.Interop.Excel'

How can I solve this?

Many thanks!

Comment: The code you posted appears to work as expected other than missing the first/last row of the grid. I am running Excel Obj `14 lib, but since the error appears to be coming from the first three lines, have you tried to take the “underscore” off the Excel.properties? It should still work without it. Just a guess.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean when you say "to take the “underscore” off the Excel.properties".

Comment: An underscore is the “_” character! The errors indicate “_Application”, “_Workbook” and “_Worksheet” do not exist. Try to change the values to “Application”, “Workbook” and “Worksheet” WITHOUT the underscore.